# How can I loop in unlimited scroll sites to extract every page?

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, scrapy

**I don't want to use api to extract data i just want to learn this way for the project.**
The element for next page is not visible and the website has unlimited scroll. I have scraped the first page but i cannot scrape or create a loop to extract till the end page. The website is https://www.futuretools.io/.

````
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod

from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

class ToolsSpider(scrapy.Spider):

 name = "tools"

 def start_requests(self):

 yield scrapy.Request("https://www.futuretools.io", 

 meta=dict(

 playwright = True,

 playwright_page_methods = [

 PageMethod("wait_for_selector", "div.jetboost-list-wrapper-n5zn > div.w-dyn-items div.tool"),

 ]
 ))
 async def parse(self, response):
 for tool in response.css("div.jetboost-list-wrapper-n5zn > div.w-dyn-items div.tool"):

 yield{

 'title': tool.css('div.div-block-18 a.tool-item-link---new::text').get(),

 'description': tool.css('div.tool-item-description-box---new::text').get(),

 'total_votes': tool.css('div.list-upvote div.text-block-52::text').get(),

 'category': tool.css('div.collection-list-wrapper-9 div.text-block-53::text').get()

 }```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can just [scroll](https://scrapeops.io/python-scrapy-playbook/scrapy-playwright/#3-scroll-down-infinite-scroll-pages) till `div.tool.w-dyn-item.w-col.w-col-6:nth-child(number_of_items)` appear

**Edit:**

Here I made use of next_page button. You could take scrolling approach but this seems cleaner.

```
import scrapy


class ToolsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "tools"
    start_urls = ['https://www.futuretools.io/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for tool in response.css("div.jetboost-list-wrapper-vq3k.w-dyn-list div.tool.w-dyn-item.w-col.w-col-6"):
            yield {
                'title': tool.css('div.div-block-18 a.tool-item-link---new::text').get(),
                'description': tool.css('div.tool-item-description-box---new::text').get(),
                'total_votes': tool.css('div.list-upvote div.text-block-52::text').get(),
                'category': tool.css('div.collection-list-wrapper-9 div.text-block-53::text').get()
            }

        next_page = response.css('.w-pagination-next.next')
        if next_page:
            yield response.follow(next_page.attrib['href'], callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: Thank you soo much @Daniel for the solution. What does QuoteItem.css means here? Also, if it's possible can you merge your code with mine to make it workable and post full code. I am a beginner so i am still getting error with your solution. Again, Thanks for helping out it means a lot.

Comment: You can see the workings of code through the link. I thought you might want to change how you interact with the browser. Also, there is a next button on the button of the page. It just disappears when page is loading. You can see that through dev-tools. `Right click on element` > `Break on` > `subtree modification`

Comment: QuoteItem() is a class you need to import from quotes_js_scraper. I forgot to add the parentheses. You might not need it.

Comment: Thank you Daniel for being kind enough to explain. I will try again with these information.

Comment: You are amazing Daniel. I was on it for whole day surfed the whole internet and got nothings. Thank you so much this solves everything . I hope i will get better someday.